# Add trailing zeroes and keep them 0.00 for subsequent processing

Tags: excel, vba

How can I get values like 38.8 and 1 to be 38.80 and 1.00.

I could get cells to display the value correctly but it's real value remains 38.8 when you then try to move it or do anything with it and in the function bar it shows as 38.8.

Column 17 is the price or double I need two decimal places. I then need to move it to another cell to add to the string I'm replacing with RegEx and keep the decimal places.

```vb
Sub MacroReplaceText()
' Declare variables
Dim RowNum As Integer
Dim StrNew As String
Dim DblPrice As Double
' Set starting point of row
RowNum = 2

Dim regex As Object
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
' Set pattern to search for
regex.Pattern = "-.+"
' Set regex to only find first result
regex.Global = False

'Loop through every row that has a value in column 11
Do While Cells(RowNum, 11).Value <> ""
    'Set Price format
    Cells(RowNum, 17).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    DblPrice = Cells(RowNum, 17)
    'Create replacement text string
    StrNew = "- " & Cells(RowNum, 16) & " @ $" & DblPrice
    
   'Replace found pattern
   'Cells(RowNum, 11) = "STC's " & Cells(RowNum, 11)
   'Cells(RowNum, 11) = regex.replace(Cells(RowNum, 11), StrNew)
   'Cells(RowNum, 15) = Cells(RowNum, 11)
   
    RowNum = RowNum + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

This is the text
[image: Text needed to replace]

This is the result after running macro
[image: Result]

Comment: If you want to use the formatted text that is being displayed instead of the value, you can use `Cells(RowNum, 16).Text` - Alternatively, `Format$(Cells(RowNum, 16), "$#,##0.00")`

Comment: Thanks both of those work, sorry I tried all the format options I could find and none of them worked I guess I don’t really understand how these functions work full as I couldn’t find a lot on Format only .numberFormat etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused. But if you want to keep `DblPrice` as a Double, and also have `DblPrice` to appear in your string, formatted as you show in your screenshot, then you can use the vba `Format` function:

```
StrNew = "- " & Cells(RowNum, 16) & " @ $" & Format(DblPrice,"Currency")
```

or similar.

Comment: Omg I thought I tried that but instead I think I set the variable dblprice = Format(cells(rownum, 17),”currency”) and also with another variable and both didn’t work. This worked perfectly thanks.